# Access work javascript in main site from iframe

Tags: javascript, security, iframe

I have a problem with the script loaded from outside site. Sometimes not loaded and all script in main site is stoped by core js in browsers.

I put the script into the iframe. JS wants to eliminate the influence of the iframe to the main page and do not know how to do it.

SECURITY="restricted"?

Comment: This isn't really clear. Could you put an example of your problem in jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

```
parent.document
```

should give you the parent document.
If you want anything else in the parent window, use the "parent" instead of "window".
This works in firefox, but the newer IE is very restricted with javascript. I don't know if they are gonna let you do it

Comment: How blocks  parent document in iframe tag?